# View PDF using Childbrowser plugin of phonegap for window phone

Tags: cordova

I am using Phonegap-1.4.1 for Window phone and merged child browser pluging ,its allowing to show other URL but When I tried for PDF it didnt,I google it and found this

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/07/updating-phonegap-s-childbrowser-plugin-to-handle-local-files/

but its for iOS widgets and I wanted it for Windows phone.

Please if any one have any idea,plz let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this plugin with Phonegap Android and it does not show any PDF'. The reason is that Android does not come with a built in PDF reader. What you can do is use google docs viewer to view PDF'. Pass the google docs viewer URL in the childbrowser plugin